# Regastar nome das colunas e valores do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu quero pegar o nome das colunas de uma tabela e seus respectivos registros.. Ex: Tenho a tabela **cadastros** e nela tem as colunas **nome, login, senha** e existe 2 registros gravados nessa tabela, ficando +- assim:

**nome = alisson / login=admin / senha = 123**

**nome = alisson2 / login=admin2 / senha = 123**

Então eu gostaria de pegar o nome das colunas (**nome,login,senha**) e pegar o valor dos 2 registros que tem nela (**alisson, admin, 123 e alisson2, admin2, 123**)

```
<?php

protected function ListColumn($table){

        $Query = $this->connect->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table}");
        $Query->execute();

        while($e = $Query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $colunas[] = $e['Field'];

        }

        return array($colunas);
    }


QuerySearch = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE login LIKE '%teste%'");
        $QuerySearch->execute();

        $Retornados = $QuerySearch->rowCount();

        if($Retornados > 0){

            while($b = $QuerySearch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                foreach($this->ListColumn($table) as $field){               

                    $s[] = $field;
                }

            }

            echo json_encode($s);

        }else{

            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Nada foi encontrado com o termo informado.', 'result'=>'0'));
        }
?>
```

Comment: Não ficou muito clara sua duvida...

Comment: @PapaCharlie editei a pergunta

Comment: Estou tentando entender mas não consigo... Qual a relação com os nomes das colunas? No seu código, qual a linha executa o que você pretende fazer?

Comment: Eu só quero pegar os nomes das colunas de uma tabela e juntamente com o nome, obter os registros

Comment: Vais buscar os nomes das tabelas e depois os registos.

Comment: eu até sei fazer com mysql_fetch_array, só que eu não irei informar por exemplo que quero os nomes, fazendo por ex $data["nome"]... o "nome" será o resultado da captura das colunas pra ele formar um $data[$campo]

Comment: @alisson continue usando PDO , estas no caminho certo. Acredito que a resposta do papa é o que você quer

Comment: Pena que eu só vi os comentários dois anos depois :) Segue a versão com `mysqli`, mais adequada para os visitantes que não precisam de "portabilidade" de DB: [Como listar uma query sem saber o que vai ser retornado?](/questions/41293/70)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, posso estar enganado sobre a sua duvida, mas pelo que entendi, você quer fazer uma consulta e retornar todos os campos da tabela e fazer a listagem sem a definição do campo na `$row`

> usar `$row[$field]` no lugar de `$row['ID']`

---

Se for realmente isso, minha sugestão é um simples `foreach`:

```
$pdo = new \PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx' , 'xxx' , 'xxx' );
$stmt = $pdo-> prepare( 'select * from table' );
if( $stmt-> execute() )
{
    while( $row = $stmt-> fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
    {
        foreach( $row as $field => $value )
        {
            echo 'my field: ' . $field . ' - ' . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Desta forma você tem `$campo` e `$valor`