# Leitura de campos de uma tabela

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo uma leitura a uma tabela que possui 12 campos (campo_1, campo_2, ..., campo_12).

Após cada leitura de um registro, preciso fazer um tratamento repetido para cada coluna (apenas muda o nome do campo).
Então, preciso repetir o código 12 vezes, uma para cada coluna.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum código que faça um *loop*, tipo `FOR`...`NEXT` ou algo similar, onde o tratamento seria escrito apenas uma vez, variando o nome do campo.

**Exemplo de como estou fazendo:**

```
$string_sql = "select * from TABELA where CHAVE = '" . $key . "'";
$query = ibase_query($connection,$string_sql);
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)) {
    if ($row->CAMPO_1 <> 0) {
        .......
        .......
    }

    if ($row->CAMPO_2 <> 0) {
        .......
        .......
    }

    if ($row->CAMPO_3 <> 0) {
        .......
        .......
    }

    .......
    .......
    .......
    .......

    if ($row->CAMPO_12 <> 0) {
        .......
        .......
    }
}
```

**O que pensei:**

```
$string_sql = "select * from TABELA where CHAVE = '" . $key . "'";
$query = ibase_query($connection,$string_sql);
while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)) {
    for ($x = 1 ; $x <= 12 ; $x++) {
        if ($row->CAMPO_$x <> 0) {
            .......
            .......
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Regastar nome das colunas e valores do MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27216/regastar-nome-das-colunas-e-valores-do-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o colega Rafael falou, pegue as propriedades do objeto usando `get_object_vars`, então você concatena o `$x` do laço com o nome dos campos:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {

   $campos = get_object_vars($row);
   for ($x = 1 ; $x <= 12 ; $x++) {
      if ($campos['campo_'.$x] <> 0) {
         // faz alguma coisa
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Sim...consegui com as dicas. Obrigado.

Comment: Então vc pode marcar a resposta que achou melhor. Abs!

Comment: Sou usuário novo aqui. Como faço essa marcação que vc mencionoou ?

Comment: Ao lado da resposta tem um ícone para clicar.

Answer (score 1):

Como `$row` é um objeto você pode pegar as propriedade com `get_object_vars($row)`.

Dá uma olhada [no manual de `get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-object-vars.php).

Ou você pode recuperar como um array e retornar as chaves, acho que existem várias soluções.

Comment: Consegui com a sua sugestão. Obrigado pela ajuda.